# serialize post from form inside colorbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I am trying to serialize form data from a form that is inside color-box. I get the form to submit but the form data isn't there.

Here is what I am using to try to get the form data.

```
 $("#submitForm").live("click",function(){
  var data = $(this).closest("form").serialize();
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_cc.php",
        data: "data="+data,
        success:function(data){
            $().colorbox({html: data, open:true});
        }
      });
    return false;
  });
```

Has anybody used colorbox with a form inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure that 'data' is what you expect it to be, because your call to colorbox looks fine to me.  It would help to see an actual link.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing this:

```
data: "data="+data,
```

It should just be

```
data: data,
```

`serialize()` will already give you the form controls in the form of `name=value` pairs separated by `&`.